# How can I get the time in seconds since midnight

Tags: java, android, datetime

This is a sample code which works. How can I get the time in seconds since midnight in Java Android

```
long time = 1450853970
    DateTime.DateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    long unix_time = DateTime.DateParse(DateTime.Date(time * 1000)) / 1000  
    long time_in_seconds = time - unix_time + (DateTime.TimeZoneOffset * -3600)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Calendar`, as `Date` is weird))

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();

midnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
midnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
midnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
midnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

long difference = now.getTimeInMillis() - midnight.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getSecondsFromMidnight(DateTime d) {
    DateTime pastMidnight = d.minusDays(1).withHourOfDay(23).withMinuteOfHour(59).withSecondOfMinute(59);
    Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(pastMidnight, d);

    return seconds.getSeconds();
}
```